# How do I swap the order of individually plotted geom_cols?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My research has showed that reordering bar charts can be done by introducing a column that is an ordered factor. Problem is in my case since I am individually creating these geom_col elements it seems like it is not taking into account the ordered factor. How is ggplot interpreting the below code that is not getting it to arrange properly?

What I want is to have Female on top and Male on bottom.

```
# Data

clm <- c("covid","covid","all","all")
sex <- c("female","male","female","male")
percent <- c(0.6, 0.2, .4, .8)

# Colors

dark <- '#008AFE' # blue
lightest <-'#CCE8FF'
light_accent <-'#FFCB93' #peachy
lightest_accent <- '#FFE5C9'



df <- data.frame("clm" = clm,"sex" = sex, "percent" = percent)


gender_claim <- df %>%
  arrange(sex) %>%
  mutate(sex=factor(sex, levels = c("male","female"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = percent)) +
  geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "male") & 
                       (df$clm == "all"), ], 
           fill = lightest_accent, width = .25) +
  geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "male") & 
                       (df$clm == "covid"), ], 
           fill = dark, width = .15) +
  geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "female") & 
                                             (df$clm == "all"), ], 
           fill = lightest_accent, width = .25) +
  geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "female") & 
                                             (df$clm == "covid"), ], 
           fill = dark, width = .15) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),
                     labels = function(y) paste0(round(y*100,0),"%"), 
                     seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add scale_x_discrete(limits=rev) to your plot. The following code worked for me.

```
gender_claim <- df %>%
    arrange(sex) %>%
    mutate(sex=factor(sex, levels = c("male","female"))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = percent)) +
    geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "male") & 
                           (df$clm == "all"), ], 
             fill = lightest_accent, width = .25) +
    geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "male") & 
                           (df$clm == "covid"), ], 
             fill = dark, width = .15) +
    geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "female") & 
                           (df$clm == "all"), ], 
             fill = lightest_accent, width = .25) +
    geom_col(data = df[(df$sex == "female") & 
                           (df$clm == "covid"), ], 
             fill = dark, width = .15) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),
                       labels = function(y) paste0(round(y*100,0),"%"), 
                       seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) + 
    coord_flip()+scale_x_discrete(limits=rev)

gender_claim
```

[image: Swapped column of individually plotted columns ggplot]

Comment: In this case it worked, but what is the issue that I cant simply specify the factor order?

Comment: You're almost there, but `coord_flip` also reverses the x axis (now y). So if you wanted to do this with factor levels, you just need to swap them.